# Adding Libgdx Scrollbar to TextArea

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, textarea, scrollpane

So I've been searching around and for the life of my cannot figure out how to correctly do this. I simply have a small text area and want to be able to scroll through it. I've been told it's as easy as adding the TextArea to a ScrollPane, but it appears to be more complicated than that. Here's the gist of my code:

```
Skin defaultSkin = newSkin(DEFAULT_SKIN_FILEPATH +"uiskin.atlas", DEFAULT_SKIN_FILEPATH
+"uiskin.json");
TextArea textArea = new TextArea(levelLoader.getCodeSnippet(), defaultSkin);
ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane(textArea, defaultSkin);
pane.setForceScroll(false, true);
pane.setFlickScroll(false);
pane.setOverscroll(false, true);
pane.setBounds(0f, 20f, game.getWindowWidth(), 300f);
gui.addActor(pane);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gui);
setIsCreated(true);
```

levelLoader.getCodeSnippet() returns a string containing a multi-line piece of text from a .txt. The TextArea appears in the game window, and the multi-lined text also appears. However, I can only scroll through the text with the arrow keys. I forced the scrollbar to display itself, but it occupies the entire right side of the window like this: 
http://s27.postimg.org/vqws36k77/pic.png
It will not scroll and thinks there are not multiple lines to scroll through even though there are evident by scrolling through with the arrow keys. I've also tried making the textArea larger than the scrollPane, but might have done it incorrectly. What am I doing wrong here?

Update: I've tried both placing the ScrollPane inside of a table and setting the cell size of the table. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not best solution. I guess it is LIBGDX update layout bug.
This is workaround solution that works for me:

Set pref. rows manually and update scroll layout, when the number of the rows is changed.

`textArea.setPrefRows(numberOfScrollLines); 
//numberOfScrollLines = text.split("\n").length
pane.layout();`